# Unable to Filter Array from API on VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, nativescript, nativescript-vue

Im working on Nativescript-Vue app and im trying to solve this.

**Situation**

I receive data from API. Below is the structure of data that i receive from api

```
{
"count": 9,
"results": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "createdOn": "2020-04-08T12:10:46.924551+05:45",
        "modifiedOn": "2020-04-08T12:10:47.236475+05:45",            
        "gender": "male",
        "age": 32,
        "status": "active",

    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "createdOn": "2020-04-08T12:10:46.924551+05:45",
        "modifiedOn": "2020-04-08T12:10:47.236475+05:45",            
        "gender": "male",
        "age": 32,
        "status": "active",

    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "createdOn": "2020-04-08T12:10:46.924551+05:45",
        "modifiedOn": "2020-04-08T12:10:47.236475+05:45",
        "age": 34,
        "status": "inactive",

    },
    {
        "id": 6,
        "createdOn": "2020-04-08T12:10:46.924551+05:45",
        "modifiedOn": "2020-04-08T12:10:47.236475+05:45",
        "age": 65,
       "status": "inactive",
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "createdOn": "2020-04-08T12:10:46.924551+05:45",
        "modifiedOn": "2020-04-08T12:10:47.236475+05:45",
        "age": 19,
        "status": "pending",

    },

]
```

Below is the vue code i have.

```
 export default {
data() {

    return{
        allData:[],
        total:[],
        active:[],
        inactive:[],
        pending:[]       

       }
},
mounted() {
   axios({ method: "GET", "url": "https://api.url" }).then(
       response =>
       {            

             this.allData = response.data.results,
             this.total = response.data.count               

         }, error => {
            console.error(error);
        }
   )       
},

computed:{
        active(){
            return this.allData.filter((status)=>{
                return this.allData.status.match("active");
                 })
            }

        },

  }
```

My objective is to show the number of records with active, inactive and pending status in the app. Im using this snippet to do this for active.

```
<Label class="numbers" :text="active.count" width="200" height="50" />
```

Can someone tell me where i am failing.

Thanks in advance.
Ashish A.

Comment: try `<Label class="numbers" :text="active.length" width="200" height="50" />`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First update your computed property like:

```
computed: {
    active() {
      return this.allData.filter(d => d.status === 'active')
    }
  },
}
```

As, using `this.allData.status` not correct because `status` is the property of the object inside the `allData` array. `this.allData[0].status` would have worked but that is not needed inside the `filter()` method, as we get each object inside filter using the `d` variable.

Then update your template like:

```
<Label class="numbers" :text="active.length" width="200" height="50" />
```

Please know that `active` here is an array and array does not have any `count` property, use `length` instead to get the count of active data.

Answer (score 1):

Your `active` filter is not doing what you actually intended it to do.

If you change it to the following, it should filter correctly - and active will return an array of items that are active. If you only care about their number, you can chain on a `.length` after the filter and it will return a number of active items instead.

```js
computed: {
  active() {
    return this.allData.filter((item) => item.status === "active");
  }
}
```

For more information about the `filter` method, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: Thank you for explaining this clearly. Appreciate it.